# React: don't show modal until all content has been properly loaded

Tags: reactjs

I've created a static React website and hosted it on Github pages.

As you can see, whenever you click on a film or a TV series, a modal will appear with the film/tv poster(loaded from the OMDb API) and some metadata. The problem is that the content loads too slowly. It takes a second(sometimes more) before before the content appears.

I get that I can't expect it to load that much faster, but I would like to not show the modal at all before everything looks nice(i.e is perfectly loaded). Perhaps by having a "Loading.." appear while we wait. It doesn't have to be anything fancy, as it's only gonna be on the screen for 1-2 seconds at most.

Do you have any advice for a React beginner?

Relevant code:

```
function ImdbInfo(props) {
    const [data, setData] = useState({ imdbData: [] });
 
    useEffect(() => {
        const imdbId = getImdbId(props.url);

        const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await axios(
                `https://www.omdbapi.com/?i=${imdbId}&apiKey=${apiKey}`,
            );
            setData(result.data);
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

    return (
        <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="metadata" onClick={props.handleClose}>
                <h1 className="modal-header">{data.Title}</h1>
                <img className="modal-poster" src={data.Poster} alt="poster" />
                <p className="modal-info">{getDirectorOrWriter(data)}</p>
                <p className="modal-info">IMDb Rating: {getImdbScore(data.Ratings)}</p>
            </div>
            {createImdbLink(props.url)}
        </div>
    );
}
```

And:

```
const MediaModal = ({ handleClose, show, data }) => {
    const showHideClassName = show ? 'modal display-block' : 'modal display-none';
    const imdbData = show ? <ImdbInfo url={data.imdbLink} handleClose={handleClose} /> : <div />;
  
    return (
      <div className={showHideClassName} onClick={handleClose}>
        <section className='modal-main'>
            {imdbData}
        </section>
      </div>
    );
};

export default MediaModal;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `loading` to `true` before making the api call and
set `loading` `false` after api returns success/failure.

Check updated code below

```
  function ImdbInfo(props) {
    const [data, setData] = useState({ imdbData: [] });
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
      const imdbId = getImdbId(props.url);

      const fetchData = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        try {
          const result = await axios(
            `https://www.omdbapi.com/?i=${imdbId}&apiKey=${apiKey}`
          );
          setData(result.data);
          setLoading(false);
        } catch (err) {
          setLoading(false);
        }
      };
      fetchData();
    }, []); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

    return (
      <div>
        {loading ? (
          <div>Loading...</div>
        ) : (
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="metadata" onClick={props.handleClose}>
              <h1 className="modal-header">{data.Title}</h1>
              <img className="modal-poster" src={data.Poster} alt="poster" />
              <p className="modal-info">{getDirectorOrWriter(data)}</p>
              <p className="modal-info">
                IMDb Rating: {getImdbScore(data.Ratings)}
              </p>
            </div>
            {createImdbLink(props.url)}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly, you create a `MediaModal` component, that has a child component `ImdbInfo`, where you fetch some data. I guess this `MediaModal` has a parent component where you toggle and use your modal: you didn't provide the code, but let's call it `MainComponent`

Instead of fetching data inside `ImdbInfo` you could fetch them in `MainComponent` and pass the result as props:

- Inside MainComponent:

```
// Onclick to toggle modal:
// - fetch data just like you did in ImdbInfo
// - then set show=true
// Then use your modal
<MediaModal handleClose={plop} show={plip} infos={fetchedData} url={imdbLink} />
```

- MediaModal:

```
const MediaModal = ({ handleClose, show, infos, url}) => {
    const showHideClassName = show ? 'modal display-block' : 'modal display-none';
    const imdbData = show ? <ImdbInfo infos={infos} url={url} handleClose={handleClose} /> : <div />;
  
    return (
      <div className={showHideClassName} onClick={handleClose}>
        <section className='modal-main'>
            {imdbData}
        </section>
      </div>
    );
};

export default MediaModal;
```

- ImdbInfo:

```
function ImdbInfo({infos, handleClose}) {
    return (
        <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="metadata" onClick={handleClose}>
                <h1 className="modal-header">{infos.Title}</h1>
                <img className="modal-poster" src={infos.Poster} alt="poster" />
                <p className="modal-info">{getDirectorOrWriter(infos)}</p>
                <p className="modal-info">IMDb Rating: {getImdbScore(infos.Ratings)}</p>
            </div>
            {createImdbLink(url)}
        </div>
    );
}
```